# Find out if you're connected to a printer

Tags: swift, macos, printing, appkit

I am using SwiftUI to build a macOS app. I have to print papers and I'm trying to see if I'm actively connected to a printer. I have a default printer set as you can see in the below image but it's currently offline. My issue is the code I have returns true that I am connected to a printer because I have a saved printer device. Is there a way to check if the printer is offline even when I'm connected?

In the image it says the printer is offline and I need to know how to get that.

[image]

Code I'm currently using that returns true:

```
func isConnectedToPrinter() -> Bool {
    let printers = NSPrinter.printerNames
        
    return !printers.isEmpty
}
```

Comment: `NSPrinter` doesn't give status as far as i'm aware. the terminal command `lpstat -p` gives a bit more information, if you want to try to call that command and integrate the output into your code